# I got to deform a mesh to another mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, faces

I' m an architect and I start to use Blender 3 months ago.

I' have to make a urban floor, and attaching the mesh of the floor joints on the floor mesh, and using *Shrinkwrap* on the joints, with the target on the floor mesh, gives me problems in rendering, in the sense that some parts of the joints are lower and others higher, going to create parts of joints hide under the floor mesh.

How can i solve the problem?

That' s the base floor mesh
[image: That' s the base floor mehs]

That' s the floor joints
[image: That' s the floor joints]

and that' s problem in rendering
[image: and that' s problem in rendering]

Comment: Hi. Could you add some images in your question to help figure how things are?

Comment: Maybe try to "project" instead of "nearest surface point" in the modifier. Then play with the options (up/down, negative/positive) depending on your surfaces.

Comment: Ok thank you, i' ll try and i let you know